# Error message in Mac terminal: "command not found: ecit". How to fix it?

Tags: terminal

Whenever I open the terminal on my Mac, an error message appears, and I am unable to type anything. The error message reads:

```
/Users/joaogomes/.zshrc:4: command not found: ecit
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
[Process completed]
```

I have tried pressing "Control + C" to interrupt any running process, closing and reopening the terminal, and restarting my computer. None of these actions have fixed the issue.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to resolve this problem. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There is a typo in one of the shell startup scripts, it should probably be `exit`.

Comment: Spefically `/Users/joaogomes/.zshrc` line `4`

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: @joaopsgomes open `.zshrc` in TextEdit; if there is no sensitive data, edit your question and paste file contents